# Ajv response number as string with coerceTypes: true

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajv

I have next schema:

```
export const User = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      minimum: 1,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      format: 'email',
    },
  },
}
```

And Ajv instance:

```
const ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true, coerceTypes: true })
```

But when I pass number Ajv response it as string:

```
//ok
 {
    "firstName": 55
}
```

When I set `coerceTypes` to `false` validation failing as it should be:

```
//error
{
    "firstName": 55
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? It looks like you describe the expected behavior of ajv. Just set `coerceTypes` as you need.